# how to make an nbconvert custom template

Tags: jupyter, python-3.5, jupyter-notebook

I am working on an El Capitan with python 3.5 and I have installed succsfully jupyter, pandoc, and latex.

I am trying to make a tempalte for nbconvert in order to edit the output in pdf (some margines do not look very nice and some code falls outside the paper).

For that reason I tried to download and play with https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert-examples as suggested in an other question. The only problem is it does not work.

For example in the citations folder the tutorial instructs me to use the `ipython nbconvert` command but it gives me the warning:

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython nbconvert` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
```

and fails. When I run it with `jupiter nbconvert` instead I am getting the same error.

I tried the full command it suggests in many versions, each fail:

the:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to latex --template citations.tplx --post pdf mynotebook.ipynb
```

understandably does not work any more since the syntax has changed. But the:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --template citations.tplx LifecycleTools
```

runs but does not create the citations.
When I run:

```
jupyter nbconvert --config ipython_nbconvert_config.py --template citations.tplx  LifecycleTools.ipynb
```

the same happens.

Any idea for correct examples or where I can find resources on how to white and run a template?

Comment: I think the second jupyter command you tried, with `--to pdf`, should work. Maybe there's a bug in setting the template when converting to PDF.

Comment: Hello Thomas, yes I think I will have to agree with you. It seems nbconvert fails to use the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I manged to use the templateby first exporting it to markdown:

```
jupyter nbconvert  --to markdown my_file.ipynb --template="mytemplate.tpl";
```

and then using the files created to build a pdf with pandoc.

```
pandoc --toc --template=mdtemplate.tex $PATHTOMYFILES/* --latex-engine=pdflatex -o $NBDIR/ROOT-Primer_v0.pdf
```